# Drag and Drop event JavaFX

Tags: java, events, javafx, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a drag and drop solution between my treetableview and some rectangles in my interface.
For now I am able to drag a row from my treeTableView and when I drag it over my rectangle, then the color of the rectangle change.
But now I would like to be notified when the drag is not over anymore, so that i can change back the color on my rectangle. But I am not able to see an event doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the drag target you have four different properties:

- [`onDragEnteredProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onDragEnteredProperty): called when drag gesture enters this `Node`
- [`onDragOverProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onDragOverProperty): called when drag gesture progresses within this `Node`
- [`onDragExitedProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onDragExitedProperty): called when drag gesture exits this `Node`
- [`onDragDroppedProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onDragDroppedProperty): called when the mouse button is released on this `Node` during drag and drop gesture

You can use this properties to define a behaviour of the target `Node`, like:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.setOnDragEntered(value -> {
    // Set the drag-over color here
});

rect.setOnDragExited(value -> {
    // Reset the original color here
});

rect.setOnDragDropped(value -> { 
    // Reset the original color here 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually i tried "onDragExited" and thought it wasn't working because the behaviour of my styled wasn't working. But in fact this makes the job. Thank you !